# Find most efficient path to visit geographic coordinates in Python

Tags: python, coordinates, gis, networkx

I have a collection of 10-20 geographic coordinates that must all be visited one after another (regardless of order). What is the best way to calculate the order in which the waypoints should be visited so that the resulting distance is minimal? I am currently using a rather naive "find next closest" solution taking each of the coordinates as the starting point, but this often results in ineffective paths. Is there a ready-made library that I can use? I looked a bit at networkx, but I'm not sure the path finding functions there are the right ones.

Comment: read up on the traveling salesman problem.

Comment: @Joel Ah-ha, it's been a while since I looked at P vs NP stuff, and I knew this had a familiar ring to it. Thanks for reminding me the name for it -- it helped me find ortools and https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/tsp